# My Swift 3 Xcode 8 code is not displaying an alert

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

This is my code, for some reason it is not displaying an alert. Please help! I've tested this thoroughly. Other stack overflow questions have said that this is the way to do it, but that is not the case for me.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let testEntrant1 = ClassicGuest()
    let testEntrant2 = MaintenanceHourlyEmployee(firstName: "a", lastName: "b", streetAddress: "c", city: "d", state: "e", zipCode: "f")
    let testEntrant3 = ManagerEntrant(firstName: "g", lastName: "h", streetAddress: "i", city: "j", state: "k", zipCode: "l")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        showFailingAlert()
    }

    func showFailingAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Access Denied", message: "You do not have permission to do that", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(action)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: In your storyboard, have you set the class to `ViewController`?

Comment: A way of testing out @Tristan_Beaton answer is to set a breakpoint inside `showFailingAlert` and see if it's getting there. (Your code looks good to me.)

Comment: its like @dfd wrote, the code looks fine. the error must be somewhere else

Comment: Try to remove everything but the code for the alert.